# Better way to write if/else conditions

Tags: php

I've got the following code where:

- `$urlParams` is the school year from 7 to 11
- `$Comms['Overall']` is the total amount of "commendations" a student has

This code iterates through the numbers based on the school year to determine which "award" a student has got.

**Is there a better way to write this code?**

```
if($urlParams['y'] == 7){
    if((300 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 599)){ $Award = "Bronze"; }
    elseif((600 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 899)){ $Award = "Silver"; }
    elseif((900 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 1199)){ $Award = "Gold"; }
    elseif((1200 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 1499)){ $Award = "Platinum"; }
    elseif($Comms['Overall'] >= 1500){$Award = "Diamond";}
}

elseif($urlParams['y'] == 8){
    if((250 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 549)){ $Award = "Bronze"; }
    elseif((550 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 849)){ $Award = "Silver"; }
    elseif((850 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 1099)){ $Award = "Gold"; }
    elseif((1100 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 1299)){ $Award = "Platinum"; }
    elseif($Comms['Overall'] >= 1300){ $Award = "Diamond"; }  
}

elseif($urlParams['y'] == 9){
    if((200 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 449)){ $Award = "Bronze"; }
    elseif((450 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 699)){ $Award = "Silver"; }
    elseif((700 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 899)){ $Award = "Gold"; }
    elseif((900 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 1099)){ $Award = "Platinum"; }
    elseif($Comms['Overall'] >= 1100){ $Award = "Diamond"; }
}

elseif($urlParams['y'] == 10){
    if((150 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 399)){ $Award = "Bronze"; }
    elseif((400 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 599)){ $Award = "Silver"; }
    elseif((600 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 799)){ $Award = "Gold"; }
    elseif((800 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 999)){ $Award = "Platinum"; }
    elseif($Comms['Overall'] >= 1000){ $Award = "Diamond"; } 
}

elseif($urlParams['y'] == 11){
    if((150 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 299)){ $Award = "Bronze"; }
    elseif((300 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 499)){ $Award = "Silver"; }
    elseif((500 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 699)){ $Award = "Gold"; }
    elseif((700 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 849)){ $Award = "Platinum"; }
    elseif($Comms['Overall'] >= 850){ $Award = "Diamond"; }
 }
```

Comment: If this code works, but just needs improvement, it's off topic here. Please post it on Code Review instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should separate these magic numbers into a new data structure. Then have some code run over it. This will be much nicer to read.

For example:

```
function getAward($year, $commends) {
    $commendationsNeeded = [
        7 => [
            "Bronze" => 300,
            "Silver" => 600,
            "Gold" => 900,
            "Platinum" => 1200,
            "Diamond" => 1500
        ],
        8 => [
            "Bronze" => 250,
            "Silver" => 550,
            "Gold" => 850,
            "Platinum" => 1100,
            "Diamond" => 1300
        ]
    ];
    $maxScore = 0;
    $maxAward = "None";
    foreach ($commendationsNeeded[$year] as $award => $needed) {
        if ($needed <= $commends && $maxScore < $needed) {
            $maxScore = $needed;
            $maxAward = $award;
        }
    }
    return $maxAward;
}

echo getAward(7, 700); // Prints "Silver"
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite being 'off-topic' you could try along these lines.

```
$param = $urlParams['y'];
$score = $Comms['Overall'];


$matrix= array(
    7 => array(
        'Bronze'    =>  range(300,599),
        'Silver'    =>  range(600,899),
        'Gold'      =>  range(900,1199),
        'Platinum'  =>  range(1200,1499),
        'Diamond'   =>  range(1500,10000)
    ),
    8 => array(
        'Bronze'    =>  range(250,549),
        'Silver'    =>  range(550,849),
        'Gold'      =>  range(850,1099),
        'Platinum'  =>  range(1100,1299),
        'Diamond'   =>  range(1300,10000)
    ),
    9 => array(
        'Bronze'    =>  range(200,449),
        'Silver'    =>  range(450,699),
        'Gold'      =>  range(700,899),
        'Platinum'  =>  range(900,1099),
        'Diamond'   =>  range(1100,10000)
    ),
    10 => array(
        'Bronze'    =>  range(150,399),
        'Silver'    =>  range(400,599),
        'Gold'      =>  range(600,799),
        'Platinum'  =>  range(800,999),
        'Diamond'   =>  range(1000,10000)
    ),
    11 => array(
        'Bronze'    =>  range(150,299),
        'Silver'    =>  range(300,499),
        'Gold'      =>  range(500,699),
        'Platinum'  =>  range(700,849),
        'Diamond'   =>  range(850,10000)
    )
);

if( $param && $matrix && array_key_exists( $param, $matrix ) ){
    $arr = $matrix[ $param ];
    foreach( $arr as $award => $range ){
        if( in_array( $score, $range ) ){
            echo 'The score of '.$score.' for `$urlParams["y"]` = '.$param.' results in an award of '.$award;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it performs the way you expect I would leave it. Or you could try to rethink the logic and combine statements that meet similar conditions. You could also look into php switch statements if you want to use a different approach. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `switch`:

```
switch ($urlParams['y']) {
case 7:
    if((300 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 599)){ $Award = "Bronze"; }
    elseif((600 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 899)){ $Award = "Silver"; }
    elseif((900 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 1199)){ $Award = "Gold"; }
    elseif((1200 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 1499)){ $Award = "Platinum"; }
    elseif($Comms['Overall'] >= 1500){$Award = "Diamond";}
    Break;
case 8:
    if((250 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 549)){ $Award = "Bronze"; }
    elseif((550 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 849)){ $Award = "Silver"; }
    elseif((850 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 1099)){ $Award = "Gold"; }
    elseif((1100 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 1299)){ $Award = "Platinum"; }
    elseif($Comms['Overall'] >= 1300){ $Award = "Diamond"; }
    Break;
case 9:
    if((200 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 449)){ $Award = "Bronze"; }
    elseif((450 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 699)){ $Award = "Silver"; }
    elseif((700 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 899)){ $Award = "Gold"; }
    elseif((900 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 1099)){ $Award = "Platinum"; }
    elseif($Comms['Overall'] >= 1100){ $Award = "Diamond"; }
    Break;
case 10:
    if((150 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 399)){ $Award = "Bronze"; }
    elseif((400 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 599)){ $Award = "Silver"; }
    elseif((600 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 799)){ $Award = "Gold"; }
    elseif((800 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 999)){ $Award = "Platinum"; }
    elseif($Comms['Overall'] >= 1000){ $Award = "Diamond"; }
    Break;
case 11:
    if((150 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 299)){ $Award = "Bronze"; }
    elseif((300 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 499)){ $Award = "Silver"; }
    elseif((500 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 699)){ $Award = "Gold"; }
    elseif((700 <= $Comms['Overall']) && ($Comms['Overall'] <= 849)){ $Award = "Platinum"; }
    elseif($Comms['Overall'] >= 850){ $Award = "Diamond"; }
    Break;
}
```

More information here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution, This is best I can think of now. feel free to change any logic if you get any error..

```
<?php
switch($urlParams['y']){

    case '7' :
    $array = array(300 , 600, 900,1200, 1500);
    $number = (int) $Comms['Overall'];
    $position  = closest($array,$number);
    $Award = getAward($position);
        break;
    case '8' :
    $array = array(250, 550,850, 1100, 1300);
    $number = (int) $Comms['Overall'];
    $position  = closest($array,$number);
    $Award = getAward($position);
        break;
    case '9' :
    $array = array(200, 450, 700, 900, 1100);
    $number = (int) $Comms['Overall'];
    $position  = closest($array,$number);
    $Award = getAward($position);
        break;
    case '10' :
    $array = array(150, 400, 600, 800, 1000);
    $number = (int) $Comms['Overall'];
    $position  = closest($array,$number);
    $Award = getAward($position);
        break;
    case '11' :
    $array = array(150, 300, 500, 700, 850);
    $number = (int) $Comms['Overall'];
    $position  = closest($array,$number);
    $Award = getAward($position);
        break;


}

function getAward($position){
    case "0" :  return "Bronze";
     break;
    case "1" : return "Silver";
     break;
    case "2" : return "Gold";
     break;
    case "3" : return "Platinum";
     break;
    case "4" : return "Diamond";
     break;
    case "5" : return "Diamond";
     break;
    case "null" : return "Diamond";
     break;
}
function closest($array, $number) {
    sort($array);
    $i=0;
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if ($a >= $number) return $i;
        $i++;
    }
    return end($array); // or return NULL;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a big swich around, because it's exactly what you are doing. You can also add a temporary variable, which will make your code a lot more readable. Also you can remove some useless parenthesis in your conditions:
`((cond1) && (cond2)) => (cond1 && cond2)`

```
$Overall = $Comms['Overall'];
switch ($urlParams['y'])
{
    case 7:
        if (300 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 599) { $Award = "Bronze"; }
        elseif (600 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 899) { $Award = "Silver"; }
        elseif (900 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 1199) { $Award = "Gold"; }
        elseif (1200 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 1499) { $Award = "Platinum"; }
        elseif $Overall >= 1500 { $Award = "Diamond"; }
    break;
    case 8:
        if (250 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 549) { $Award = "Bronze"; }
        elseif (550 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 849) { $Award = "Silver"; }
        elseif (850 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 1099) { $Award = "Gold"; }
        elseif (1100 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 1299) { $Award = "Platinum"; }
        elseif $Overall >= 1300 { $Award = "Diamond"; }
    break;
    case 9:
        if (200 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 449) { $Award = "Bronze"; }
        elseif (450 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 699) { $Award = "Silver"; }
        elseif (700 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 899) { $Award = "Gold"; }
        elseif (900 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 1099) { $Award = "Platinum"; }
        elseif $Overall >= 1100 { $Award = "Diamond"; }
    break;
    case 10:
        if (150 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 399) { $Award = "Bronze"; }
        elseif (400 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 599) { $Award = "Silver"; }
        elseif (600 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 799) { $Award = "Gold"; }
        elseif (800 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 999) { $Award = "Platinum"; }
        elseif $Overall >= 1000 { $Award = "Diamond";  }
    break;
    case 11:
        if (150 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 299) { $Award = "Bronze"; }
        elseif (300 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 499) { $Award = "Silver"; }
        elseif (500 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 699) { $Award = "Gold"; }
        elseif (700 <= $Overall && $Overall <= 849) { $Award = "Platinum"; }
        elseif $Overall >= 850 { $Award = "Diamond"; }
    break;
 }
```